# Validating values in column between two data frames in R based on conditions

Tags: r

I have two data frames.  I have to match the first two columns between `nndf` and `tndf` and if there is a match i have to check if the values in the third column is the same or not and update the third dataframe. The problem is `nndf` is longer than `tndf`.

```
nndf <- data.frame("var1" = c("ABC","ABC","DEF", "FED","DGS"), "var2" = c("xyz","abc","def","dsf","dsf"), "var3" = c(1234.21,3432.12,0.12,1232.44,873.00))

tndf <- data.frame("var1" = c("ABC","ABC","DEF"), "var2" = c("xyz","abc","def"), "var3" = c(1234.21,3432.12,0.11))

ndf <- data.frame("var1" = c("ABC","ABC"), "var2" = c("xyz","abc"))
```

I want to populate the results in the third data frame.  This data frame takes the common values from the first two columns of `nndf` and `tndf` and wherever they are common check the third column which is `1234.21` and `3432.12` and if the values are same, it returns TRUE and fill the column.  The desired output is

```
var1   var2    var3
ABC    xyz     TRUE (indicating 1234.21 and 1234.21 in first two df are same)
ABC    abc     TRUE
DEF    def     FALSE (indicating 0.12 is not equal to 0.11)
```

I tried using `forloop + if condition`.  However it iterates through each line multiple times and fills the results.

Comment: Try `tndf$var3 <- do.call(paste, tndf) %in% do.call(paste,  nndf)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%` in `base R` to create the logical vector

```
tndf$var3 <- do.call(paste, tndf) %in% do.call(paste, nndf)
tndf
#  var1 var2  var3
#1  ABC  xyz  TRUE
#2  ABC  abc  TRUE
#3  DEF  def FALSE
```

---

Or using a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tndf)[nndf, var3n := var3 == i.var3, on = .(var1, var2)]
tndf[, .(var1, var2, var3 = var3n)]
#   var1 var2  var3
#1:  ABC  xyz  TRUE
#2:  ABC  abc  TRUE
#3:  DEF  def FALSE
```

Comment: @akrun....thank you...i used the first option and since I have many vectors beyond the 3rd column....have created an adaptation of your approach.

Answer (score 4):

We could do an `inner_join` and then compare the values in two columns

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(nndf, tndf, by = c("var1", "var2")) %>%
   mutate(var3 = var3.x == var3.y) %>%
   dplyr::select(var1, var2, var3)


#  var1 var2  var3
#1  ABC  xyz  TRUE
#2  ABC  abc  TRUE
#3  DEF  def FALSE
```

Or similarly in base R

```
df1 <- merge(nndf, tndf, by = c("var1", "var2"))
df1$var3 <- df1$var3.x == df1$var3.y
```